# Iterating through a specific key set in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in python with date tuples as keys and data tuples as the values.

An example might be:

```
(1900, 1): (2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
```

where 1900 is the year 1900 and 1 is the first month, January.

The key tuples follow like so: (1900, 2), (1900, 3) and so on.

How can I iterate over a dictionary like this? Specifically the first month of every year, so the key set would look like (1900, 1)...(1910, 1) with the first item in the tuple incrementing, but the second staying the same.

Thank you for any help you can give me, since I am relatively new to python.

Comment: Your problem may have more to do with your choice of data structures. Why don't you describe the larger problem, and perhaps we can describe a better way to model your data.

Comment: You want to iterate *only* over the items where month is 1, or do you want to iterate over *all* keys?

Comment: For Eric above Martijn, I debated a list at first, it didn't work well. I'm aggregating data over certain time periods to perform calculations on them.
@MartijnPieters ONLY over the items where the month is one. The answer  below provided does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for key in sorted(my_dict, key=operator.itemgetter(1,0)):
    print(my_dict[key])
```

Comment: @user1472581 If you just want the month `1`, you may want to add an `if` block to break the for loop

Comment: Interestingly, going through my data, this returns exactly what I was looking for, the tuples from the first month of every year in my data set.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in myDict.items():
   if(key[1] == 1):
      for value in myDict[key]:
         # gave you the year too for handy access
         iterationLogic(key[0], value)
```

ah, didn't notice the sorted key access. the other post gives the logic to sort the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

My initial reaction would be that a better data structure might be a nested dict, where the first key is the year, and the second key is the month:

```
#data looks like this:
d = {1900: {1:(the data), 2:(the data)...}, 1901: {1:(the data)...}}

for year in data:
    print year[1]
```